Lubuntu 24.04 - Bookmarks from pcman-fm or from spacefm when saving or loading a file in libreoffice?
I use lubuntu 24.04 and either pcman-fm or spacefm as my file manager. The bookmarks are different between the 2 managers. When I save a file in libreoffice, I'm presented with the pcman-fm bookmarks, whereas I'd like the spacefm ones. What should I do? Thanks for your help.

In tags you mention pcmanfm-qt but in your question you mention the GTK app pcman-fm..   Which is it?   Lubuntu 24.04 uses LXQt or a Qt5 desktop thus pcmanfm-qt, where as the apps mentioned in your question are GTK3 (for LXDE) and thus a different desktop (pcmanfm-qt is running whenever you're using LXQt as it handles much of what you see on screen of the system)
